# Why the line break is not inserting after echo in following case?

Tags: php, string, newline, line-breaks, string-concatenation

I've following line of code :

```
$value['street1'] = "MCN";
$value['street2'] = "Bhavani peth spur";
$value['city'] = "Los Angeles";
$value['state_code'] = "CA";
$value['zip_code'] = 90009;



$temp_rebate_data['user_address'] = $value['street1']."".($value['street2'] ? "\n".$value['street2'] : '')."\n".$value['city']."".$value['state_code']."-".$value['zip_code'];

echo $temp_rebate_data['user_address'];

die;
```

The output of above code is as below :

```
MCN Bhavani peth spur Los AngelesCA-90009
```

The expected output should be as follows :

```
MCN,
Bhavani peth spur,
Los Angeles, CA - 90009
```

Can some one please help me where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use `<br />` also instead of "" use ","

Comment: or use `echo nl2br($data);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$temp_rebate_data['user_address'] = $value['street1'].",".($value['street2'] ? "<br />".$value['street2'] . "," : '')."<br />".$value['city'].", ".$value['state_code']." - ".$value['zip_code'];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what about commas at the end of first two lines and after the first string in last line?

Answer (score 0):

just try with shift + enter key for new line character in echo statement